# Can I create a set of list::iterators? Will they still point to the same node after I erase/insert other nodes from the same list?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to create a set of list::iterators, so that when I update other nodes in the list, my iterator still points to the same node.

```
int n;
string s;
cin >> n >> s;

list<char> str;
for (char c : s) {
    str.push_back(c);
}

vector<set<list<char>::iterator>> locations(10);
for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
    auto next = it;
    ++next;

    if (next != str.end()) {
        int l = *it - '0', r = *next - '0';
        if ((l + 1) % 10 == r) {
            locations[l].insert(it);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a compile error saying

> error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const std::_List_iterator’ and ‘const std::_List_iterator’)
> 386 |       { return __x < __y; }

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible in C++? Or should I create my own node structure and store pointers to it?

PS - I am trying to solve a problem from Google Kickstart (https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000435914/00000000008d94f5) and the string s contains only digits from 0-9.

Comment: `std::set` is an ordered container, so needs to know how to decide if an item is less than another

Comment: `std::set` requires that its elements be less-than comparable. But two list iterators cannot be compared this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a custom comparator. E.g. something like this:

```
struct CompareIterators {
  template <typename It>
  bool operator()(It iter1, It iter2) const {
    using Ptr = decltype(&*iter1);
    return std::less<Ptr>{}(&*iter1, &*iter2);
  }
};

using MySet = set<list<char>::iterator, CompareIterators>;
vector<MySet> locations(10);
```

The order of elements in `MySet` will be essentially random, unpredictable. It won't necessarily correspond to the order of nodes in the list. All it ensures is that, if you insert an iterator to the same element twice, it will only appear in the set once.

Comment: You can use `return std::less{}(&*iter1, &*iter2);` directly without needing the type explicitly.